# How can I hide navigation bar of a specific View Controller?

Tags: ios, swift

What I am trying is to set a `ViewController`(root) with a `NavigationController` that will connect with three `ViewController`.

Two of the linked `ViewController` have to have a `NavigationBar` on the top of each screen. The other one do not have to have the `Navigation bar`. Further, the root `View Controller` do not have to have a `Navigation bar`.

I hide the `NavigationBar` on the root `View Controller` as follows:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
}
```

but I am not able to hide the `Navigation bar` on the linked `View Controller` that does not have to have the `Navigation bar`.

I have also tried on the `viewDidLoad` function of the `View Controller` in which I want to hide the `Navigation bar` using:

```
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
```

but the `Navigation bar` is still being shown.

How can I hide the `Navigation bar` on a specific `View Controller`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: chek your VC may be not connected on Navigation controller

Comment: can you show the storyboard scene

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik No, I am sorry but I cannot because it is a project for a client and he does not want to show the screens of the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making mistake, in question you have set `false`in `viewDidLoad` to hide `navigationBar`, you need to set `true` instead of `false`, also try on `viewDidAppear`.

```
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
```

Comment: The `Navigation Bar` is still being shown. I have tried both options before but I only added one of them to not overextend the question.

Comment: Try to hide `navigationBar`like this way `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.hidden = true` and show like this `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.hidden = false`

Comment: I tried it as @shekharvishwakarma pointed in his answer but it also does not work. It just hide the title of the Navigation bar but not the back button and the rest of the Navigation bar.

Comment: I am sorry. Your first solution worked well. I just had an error on my code because I had an element that was referenced wrong and it crashes the Navigation bar I think but no errors was shown on the log. It is why I got confused. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can Try like this:-

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
     super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController!.navigationBarHidden = true
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
  super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.navigationController!.navigationBarHidden = false

}
```

Comment: I am sorry but the Navigation bar is still being shown.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in viewDidAppear :-

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
```

Comment: I guess that I have to add this method on the View Controller class of the element that I do not want to have a Navigation Bar but it also does not work. The Navigation bar is still being shown.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code in viewDidAppear method

```
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
```